# cell Background images are downloaded but take 5 seconds to appear right after finishing download

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want a UITableView to appear instantly after being tapped. Inside each cell of the UITableView there is a background image which is taken from Flickr, so the images must be downloaded in a background thread.

So everything works perfectly, the images download successfully in a separate thread. The problem though is that you must wait 5 seconds after they finish downloading for the images to actually appear within each cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"rightMenuCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIImageView *imgCube = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinnerFlickr = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *region = self.regions[indexPath.row];

    //default hashtag is life
    NSString *hashTag;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [region valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = TRUE;
    lblTitle.text = [region valueForKeyPath:@"name"];

    NSString *regionType = [region valueForKeyPath:@"region"];
    if ([regionType  isEqual: @"neighborhood"]) {
        hashTag = @"houses";
        cell.textLabel.text = @"neighborhood";
    } else if ([regionType  isEqual: @"locality"]) {
        hashTag = @"urban";
        cell.textLabel.text = @"locality";
    } else {
        hashTag = @"life";
        cell.textLabel.text = @"administrative_area_level_2";
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
                   ^{
                       UIImageView *imgBackground = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
                       [imgBackground setClipsToBounds:YES];

                       NSLog(@"loading image data...");
                       NSString *flickrURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domfa.de/get_image/?text=%@&lat=%f&long=%f", hashTag, self.latitude, self.longitude];
                       NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: flickrURL]];

                       UIImage *cellBG = [[UIImage alloc] init];
                       cellBG = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
                       imgBackground.image = cellBG;
                       [imgBackground reloadInputViews];

                       NSLog(@"images loaded!");

                       imgBackground.image = cellBG;
                       [spinnerFlickr stopAnimating];
                   });

    return cell;
}
```

Basically each cell gets the background image downloaded async but even after the download is complete I either have to tap a cell or wait 5 seconds and then 2/3 of the cells will then get an image loaded.

Comment: Make sure your table view is on main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch_get_global_queue()` fetches a background queue, not the main queue. You can only do UI-related things in the main queue. Your image fetch should look something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(…) , 
^{

    // Do non-UI-related things like fetch your UIImage from the network
    UIImage *image = [self fetchAndCacheImageAtURL:imageURL] ;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() , 
    ^{
        // Assign your UIImage to your UIImageView
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] ;
        if( cell )
             cell.imageView.image = image ;
    }) ;
}) ;
```

Notice that in the second `dispatch_async()` I fetch the cell again using `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is because by the time this code has run, the original cell may have been reused for a *different* index path (because, say, the user has been scrolling). In fact, there may be no cell at the current index path because that index path may have scrolled off screen. This, plus the check to see if cell is nil, ensures you're setting the image on the right cell for that index path.

Comment: Also, once you're back on the main queue, you need to account for the possibility that `cell` has been reused due to scrolling.

Comment: @AaronBrager, leftspin's code does allow for that. he is using the tableView method cellForRowAtIndexPath, which will fetch the **CURRENT** cell for the specified indexPath, even if it's a different cell, or no longer on-screen.